# MOSFET threshold voltage calculation across temperature using normalised values

Tags: mosfet

I have an application in which the gate voltage is 300mV to turn off the MOSFET which is active when on. The data sheet for the ZVN3310F specifies the threshold at 0.8V-2.4V at room temperature. A normalised threshold graph is also presented. I want to know whether the MOSFET would remain off across temperature so my question is;

1/ Would one use the temperature or the normalised threshold voltages in deriving the percentage difference in the threshold voltage across the temperature of interest?

2/ Once the percentage difference has been derived, for say a temperature of -40 degrees C, would we use the worst-case threshold tolerance of 0.8V, given that the threshold voltage is inversely proportional to temperature and multiply the percentage difference by that value?

3/ Similarly, at 125 degrees C say, would we calculate the threshold using the maximum threshold specified or stick with the minimum value of 0.8V as the worst case minimum?

e.g.

(125 Deg C - 25 Deg C) / 125 Deg C = 0.8 x 0.8V = 0.64V

Is this correct for the expected threshold voltage at 125 deg C?

Comment: How high would you want the impedance to be to = "off"?

Comment: Hi Andy, impedance can be off at about 2.4K ohms.

Comment: I think you should be OK then!

Comment: Are you saying that my method was correct and that I have a margin of 340mV?

Comment: I'm saying that in my experience only needing an off impedance greater than 2k4 is easily achieved (and exceeded) when the gate source voltage is only 300 mV on a FET with a threshold voltage of 0.8 volts minimum. I'm not leaving this as an answer, just a confirmation.

Comment: OK Andy, however, I was really seeking guidance as to whether I was on the right track in understanding the data sheet information presented by the manufacturer rather than it will or it won't work. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I think your logic is OK. But if this is a critical application, I would look to see if you can find a part where Vgs(th) is specified over temperature. Also, if you are going to buy a lot of them (100k or more), you can also ask the manufacturer for guidance. You might also be able to get high and low limit samples, then test them over temperature yourself. It is OK to be empirical instead of analytical, and it is OK to ask the manufacturer to help you.

Comment: Why do you have a 300mV minimum input. What is driving the FET? It maybe that your input voltage can be guaranteed to be lower. For example the output voltage of a CMOS gate can be guaranteed to be zero over temperature and the data sheet gives the guaranteed draw current for zero input over temperature.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get absolute values of VGS(th) from normalized data.
From the data sheet:

[image]

The variation of VGS(th) with temperature tells you the you can expect a drop in VGs(th) of 10% from 25 -125 degC. That gives you 0.1% per degC

It tells you little about an individual device VGS(th) since the range is from 0.8 min to 2.4 V max.

To be sure you are putting devices with an absolute range of VGS(th) over temperature you'd need to buy binned devices, which cost more.

Answer (score 0):

Normalised values \$K\$ from the graph of \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ and \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ versus temperature \$T\$ are coefficients to be directly applied to values of \$R_{DS}\$ and \$V_{GS}\$ at \$T_J=25^\circ C\$ quoted elsewhere in the datasheet, using a simple multiplication. No offsets or additions or subtractions, just a multiplication.

Even though it's not explicitly stated in the datasheet that \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ and \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ are quoted for \$T_J=25^\circ C\$, this is assumed.

This graph already embodies the relationship between some parameter and temperature, and by trying to obtain your own algebraic relationship between, say, \$V_{GS}\$ and temperature \$T\$, you are ignoring that the graph already does this for you. That might work for \$V_{GS(TH)}\$, because it's a straight line, but not for \$R_{DS(ON)}\$. That is *not* a straight line, a huge hint that this graph is already a function of temperature, and you shouldn't be trying to derive your own.

This isn't more complicated than multiplying whatever coefficient \$K\$ you read from the graph, with whatever value at \$T=25^\circ C\$ you find quoted elsewhere in the datasheet.

\$V_{GS(TH)}\$ is lowest at high temperature, and vice versa, so:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{GS(TH,MIN)} &= K(125^\circ ) \times V_{GS(TH,MIN,25^\circ )} \\ \\
&= 0.9 \times 0.8V \\ \\
&= 0.7V
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{GS(TH,MAX)} &= K(-40^\circ ) \times V_{GS(TH,MAX,25^\circ )} \\ \\
&= 1.1 \times 2.4V \\ \\
&= 2.6V
\end{aligned}
$$

If your circuit is to operate over the range −40°C to +125°C, then \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ could be anywhere between those two extremes. To have the MOSFET either fully on or fully off, \$V_{GS}\$ must be *well* outside that range.